# Look and feel of workflow (.net WF4, beta2)

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

can i change the standard look and feel of a sequential workflow back to the wf 3.5 look and feel? I miss the on DragOver automatically expanding arrows between the elements.

If this is not possible, can i change the xaml of my activities to a similar to .net 3.5 wf visibility?

Thanks!

Comment: By deriving from WorkflowViewElement instead of ActivityDesigner you are able to paint on a white board without the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your awnser, but i found a solution for me:

By deriving from WorkflowViewElement instead of ActivityDesigner you are able to paint on a white board without the header. In this way you are able to do it from the scratch. Additionaly you can derive from your own class which defines several things.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not a simple setting that does this. If you're really desperate, you can, by doing a significant amount of work. Which would be creating your own custom designers, for Sequence (mainly).

Answer (score 0):

In 4.0, we can design our own style of activity using Activity Designer. If you want to get the old style, you will have to design it on ur own. This video will help you go further.

```
http://bloggersguides.net/media/p/187.aspx
```